# Glade GtkHeaderBar, add two children on both sides?

Tags: gtk, glade

I have searched existing questions, and the answer said change the pack type but the answer did not give details. I could add a button and change its pack type to "End", but if I try to add another child to set its pack type to "Start", I get the following error message that it needs some sort of placeholder. How do I do that? How do I add, in the example below, add another button on the left side of the header bar?

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">440</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <object class="GtkHeaderBar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes">Damn complex</property>
        <property name="subtitle" translatable="yes">why</property>
        <property name="show-close-button">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="pack-type">end</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

---

PS: I could achieve that by adding children programmatically in C#, but I still have not found a way to do this within Glade.

[image]

```cs
    private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("MainWindow"))
    {
        builder.Autoconnect(this);
        DeleteEvent += Window_DeleteEvent;
        var btn1 = new Button() { Label = "Left"};
        var btn2 = new Button() { Label = "Right" };
        header1.PackStart(btn1);
        header1.PackEnd(btn2);
        header1.ShowAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Change "Number of Items" to 2, and then add 2 buttons. Change each button's pack type.

[image]